# Http.post is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await, axios

I am trying to hit an api request using global Http file using axios and async await method but its giving me an error

**Error:** _Http.default.post is not a function

**Http.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default async function() {
  await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token').then(value => {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://example.com/api' : 'https://example.com/api'
    if(value){
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + value
    }
    axios.defaults.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
  
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      response => response,
      error => {
        // if(error.response.status === 401){
        //     store.dispatch(logout());
        // }
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
    )
    return axios
  })
}
```

**axios**

```
return Http.post('login', user).then((response) => {
    const data = response.data.data
    console.log('authentication success login: ', data)
    AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', data.token_data.access_token)
    AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user))
    return user
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like the following failure

1. Not return anything in the http default function
2. the consumer of the http default function is not call the method

Here I give you some example

Http.js

```
export default function () {
    try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
        axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
                ? "http://example.com/api"
                : "https://example.com/api";
        if (token) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
        }
        axios.defaults.headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
        axios.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => response,
            (error) => {
                /* if(error.response.status === 401){ store.dispatch(logout()); }*/
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
        return axios;
    } catch (e) { throw new Error(e) }
}
```

Then in your consumer

```
Http().post('login', user).then((response) => {
    const data = response.data.data
    console.log('authentication success login: ', data)
    AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', data.token_data.access_token)
    AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user))
    return user
  })
```

Comment: It's giving me the error -> _Http.default.get is not a function